# How to listen kafka events as schema level

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new in Kafka, I'm trying to listen events with schema level .I have multiple events from same topic but schema name is different . I want to listen particular schema events only.

**Sample of Kafka Producer events:**
  **Example 1:**

```
{"id":"237","metadata":{"timestamp":1464275609527,**"schema”:”customer_add”**,”schemaVersion":1,"type":"EVENT","routingKey":{"type":"simple","value":"null"},"lookupKey":{"type":"simple","value":"null"},"tenant":"java-consumerapis","stream”:” DEAL”,”sender":""},"data":{"user_id":"1212315","name":"abhinav agraawal","mobile":"7624444444”,”email":"user1@gmail.com”}}
```

**Example 2:**

```
{"id":"237","metadata":{"timestamp":1564275609527,**"schema”:”customer_call”**,”schemaVersion":1,"type":"EVENT","routingKey":{"type":"simple","value":"null"},"lookupKey":{"type":"simple","value":"null"},"tenant":"java-consumerapis","stream”:” DEAL”,”sender":""},"data":{"user_id":"1212331","name”:"Divya agraawal","mobile":"7624453553”,”email":"user13@gmail.com”}}
```

Here both events are producing from `DEAL` topic but schema of both events are event so I want to listen only `customer_call schema` events.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "DEAL", groupId = "group_id")
public void consume(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);

    logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Consumed Message -> %s", message));


    String bootstarpserver="127.0.0.1:9092";
    String groupId="user011";
    String topic="DEAL";


    // create topic
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstarpserver);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,groupId);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");


    // create consumer

    KafkaConsumer<String,String> kafkaConsumer=new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

    // subscribe consumer to our topic
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));


    while (true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String,String> record : records){
            logger.info("key :: "+ record.key() + " value is :: " +record.value());
            logger.info(("partition ::  "+ record.partition()+ "offset::  "+ record.offset()));
        }


    }
```

Here I'm listening all events but can I filter my events on Kafka consumer level.

Answer (score 0):

You can  partition the messages using `schema` field as the key. Messages with the same key will be placed in the same partition and hence, you only need to spin up a consumer and force it to read only the partition(s) that you need.

Although the most simple solution is to filter out the messages in your inner `for-loop`, I wouldn't recommend this for many reasons (offset management, bad design etc.).

Comment: According to first solution I have to listen all events then I can filter according to my requirement .Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sharma Yes that is correct. But this is not an ideal solution to be honest and you should avoid it.

Comment: then how can I listen schema level events only?

Comment: Thank you @Giorgos ,I changed my topic name and producing only necessary events through that Topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily if you are using streaming API, if you need it in consumer API you can do that using java 8,

```
KStream<String,String> inputStream = builder.stream("topicname");
KStream<String,String> filtered = inputStream.filter((k,v)->v.
                  contains("\"schema\":\"customer_call\""));
```

Comment: I'm using Kafka and my events are coming from Kafka topic.

Comment: @sharma streaming API also from Kafka only you can use that one..!!